# Angular - Unexpected token x in JSON at position 1 - response starts with [

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-http

I am sending `$http` request to my server and my response format is `[SERVICE_NAME = XYZ][PRAMA = YZR]`, after the request finished I am getting this error:

```
SyntexError: Unexpected token S in JSON position 1 at Object.parse
```

I think it is because the response starts with `[` , anyone jas faced and solved that problem?
Here is my `$http` request:

```
  var promise = $http({method : 'GET', url : baseUrl, headers:{"Content-Type":text/html}, params:queryParams}).then(function(response){
       console.log(response);
       retuen response.data;
    }, function(error){
         console.log(error)
    })
   return promise;
};
```

I know my `response` is not a vaild `JSON`, still I need to parse it.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the response you are getting is not JSON. Legal JSON would look like `{"SERVICE_NAME":"XYZ","PRAMA":"YZR"}`

Comment: I know it is not a json, and I cant change it(from my DB).

Comment: Let me edit the question.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh - edit it.

Comment: Are you using `PHP` or `Java` or any other sever side language?

Comment: Java - j2ee as my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't return your response with `application/json` content type.
If your response have a `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json`, Angular will automatically parse the JSON.
Return your response with `text/plain` content type to avoid this.

Another option is to set the response transform function manually, for example:

```
$http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'GET',
  transformResponse: [function (response) {
      // Data response is plain text at this point
      // So just return it, or do your parsing here
      return data;
  }]
});
```

Comment: Trying and posting the result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure from server side to send the data as `text/plain`
This code can save you.

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
```

Comment: Trying and posting the result.

Comment: I have add this to my server and it helped solving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but why your header is like: `headers:{"Content-Type":text/html}`, it looks wrong. Why not `headers:{"Content-Type": 'text/html'}`

Also, Content-type header indicates only encoding of your content, but not of the answer, try to add "Accept" header:

```
headers:{'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
```

Here is the official W3C specification of protocols and headers https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling error in test/html

```
 var promise = $http({method : 'GET', url : baseUrl, headers:{"Content-Type":text/html}, params:queryParams}).then(function(response){
       console.log(response);
       retuen response.data;
    }, function(error){
         console.log(error)
    })
   return promise;
};
```

Comment: No it is "Content-Type":'text/html' just a typo.